# Avoiding a specified area using a custom location extension layer

Tags: javascript, here-api

In here maps is it possible to avoid specific areas using an array of bounding boxes as a parameter like this:

```
function calculateRoute(platform) {
  var router = platform.getEnterpriseRoutingService(),
    parameters = {
      waypoint0: '50.0522,8.2180',
      waypoint1: '50.0957,8.5280',
      mode: 'fastest;truck',
      avoidareas: '50.1062,8.2811;50.0180,8.4253'};

  router.calculateRoute(parameters,
    function (result) {
      alert(result);
    }, function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```

You can find this code in the following documentation: 
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/route-avoiding-a-specified-area

I am trying to find the way to specify the avoid areas as a layer but I didn't find anything in the documentation. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Note: A layer can be upload in here maps using the custom location extension and then is posible to retrieve the layer as an id.

Comment: isn't the `avoidareas` field for the same purpose. It is supposed to be an array of bounding boxes

Comment: I looked in all the documentation but I didn't find it so I guess it doesn't exist

Comment: What did you not find?

Comment: the avoid areas as a layer id parameter as you said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Route Extension is what you need (developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/quick-start-block-a-road.html). You can upload an overlay map to avoid specific areas.